# Hardware and software required for IPhone application development

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iPhone application development. I am going to develop an application and deploy on the iPhone. 
So i want to know what are the software and hardware requirements to install the iPhone SDK.

Presently i am having Intel core 2 Duo processor with 2GB ram and Windows XP operating system.

So please suggest me what hardware and software to get started for a IPhone development

Comment: Not just any Mac, a Mac computer running OS X 10.9.4 or later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an Apple computer. I would make sure it supports, is capable of running, the to-to-released OS X Mavericks (OS X 10.9). I would not recommend less than 4 GB of ram for development.

As for the programming environment, OS X is a UNIX system and as such it comes with most of the tools you need to develop. The IDE must be downloaded seperately from Apple, its called "XCode". The current version of the IDE is 4.x but version 5.x will be released once Mavericks is out.

XCode comes with an iOS emulator, so you do not need to have an actual iPhone during development, it is however recommenced since working in a virtual environment is never the same as working on the actual hardware (Host-Target Development Model).
In case you choose to use the iOS emulator, more RAM and possibly an SSD disk will speed things up.

XCode also comes with a dynamic tracing tool called Instruments. Instruments is based on the DTrace tracing framework which was originally developed by Sun Microsystems on the Solaris platform.

You need a iOS Developers account from apple, you can get one at developer.apple.com for about  100$ (depending on your country).

As for books, you should consitter buying a book on Objective-C and make sure you are fairly familiar with it before diving into the iPhone SDK.  The book I used in the past was [Programming Objective C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032188728X). There is a tutorial on Objective-C on apples website, but I would not attempt to follow it unless you are confident with Object-Oriented Paradigms.

Apples Developers website has a nice collection of tutorials, as well as videos on iPhone development.

Comment: i have experience in java and i don't know much about C.So without C is it not possible

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. You can not use JAVA to develop applications for iPhone.

Comment: if your fundamentals are clear in java you can easily learn objective - C and iphone application development with the iphone cookbook i've also switched from java to objective-C :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need an apple's Mac Mini or any apple pc to get started with iphone development once you have that you need Xcode which is free available on apple's developer site used for iphone application development.

Comment: To be more precise, any Mac capable of running MacOSX 10.8.4 - and likely within the next 6 months, 10.9.x.